# Interaction between MVC models in GUI application

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller

I am currently writing a GUI application and as it grows it becomes increasingly messy so I decided to implement an MVC design.

Say I have a model for a panel containing entities with properties, e.g name and id, and I have another model for a panel where the properties for an entity can be edited.

Is the best way to link these two making the controller for the entity panel a listener on the properties model and updating the entity when an action is fired?
Tell me if this is stupid as I am new to MVC designs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Say I have a model for a panel containing entities with properties, e.g name and id, and I have another model for a panel where the properties for an entity can be edited.

This is a simple example, but ok.

You have a model class that contains the properties and the getters and setters for the properties.

You have a GUI class that contains the JPanel where the user can enter the existing properties.

You have another GUI class that contains the JPanel where the user can change the existing properties.

The enter GUI class reads the values from the model class, so that the class can verify that the values entered by the user are correct.  The enter GUI class **does not modify** the values in the model class.

The change GUI class triggers a controller class when the OK button is clicked.  The controller class modifies the values in the model class.

Let's summarize.

1. The GUI can read values from the model.
2. The GUI **must not update** values in the model.
3. The controller will update values in the model.
4. The controller may update the state of the GUI (refresh / repaint)

Comment: 1+ Also the view must somehow be notified of any changes to the model, either directly or through the control, depending on what MVC subtype is used.